# Oracle MAF and requesting permissions in Android 6.0 (API level 23)

Tags: java, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, oracle-maf

I have an MAF application that uses the devices camera to take a picture. Everything was working fine until I tested it on an S6 running API 23, where it crashed with:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=3432, uid=10060 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

As far as I can tell this is because of the way Android are handling permission in the newer API's, noted here:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

So I followed the instructions on how to request permission during run-time (I've installed Android Support Libraries), the problem is, the method signature looks like this:

```
int checkSelfPermission (Context context, 
            String permission)
```

I cannot find a way to get a reference to the context (the example in the provided link also uses an Activity, same problem there). I just don't have the faintest clue how to do this from within MAF, as it seems Application/Activity objects are not exposed.

I have tried simply extending Activity in one of my classes and attempted to call the checkSelfPermission method with `this` but then I get run-time errors, after reading up on what an Activity is I understand why this is wrong.

tl:dr

How do we handle the new Android 6 (API level 23) run-time permission requests with oracle's mobile application framework?

Edit:
So as per the discussion in the comments we can see the app is supposed to still function normally on Android 6, even if you're not requesting permissions at run-time.
So I had a look at the AndroidManifest.xml file that MAF is generating on build, and I can see that the permission (from the above exception) `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not present:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <permission android:name="com.bsaf.atlas.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.bsaf.atlas.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Also interesting, is that the GPS location does not update either, and the log is constantly posting this:

```
07-07 02:07:13.089  2174  2174 E LocationProvider: Caught security exception registering for location updates from system. This should only happen in DumpRenderTree.
```

So my next question is, how do I influence AndroidManifest.xml within MAF? And why is this struggling with location updates?

Comment: Oracle MAF is not yet certified with Android 6/API level 23, Android 5/API 21 is the current certified level - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/documentation/maf231certmatrix-3039175.html.  Let me ask the MAF product management team when support for Android 6 is due, as well as when runtime permissions will be supported.

Comment: Sorry, a minor correction. We support Android 6 at runtime, but Android 5 for build time.  I still need to check how we cover the new Android 6 runtime permissions though.

Comment: Wow fantastic, thank you for the response! I await more information eagerly.

Comment: Received a response from the MAF PM team overnight: Support for API 23 is due in an upcoming MAF release, most likely MCS v2.4.  Due to Oracle policies as an Oracle employee I can't publicly commit to an eta for this version but to say approximately by end of year.  If you'd like more details my suggestion is to raise a query with Oracle Support.

Comment: A further response: "As you mention MAF apps are supported on Android 6 devices and there are a number of Android 6 devices listed in the certification matrix. When installed on these devices, the app behavior will be same as the apps on Android 5, in this particular case, the user will not see dynamic permissions instead, he will see the permissions used by the app listed at the time of App download from GooglePlay store."

Comment: And: "MAF apps are targeted for API 21 & we don't allow developers to change this so this issue may not be related to Android 6. If the customer is using Camera & enabled Camera plugin in maf-application.xml there shouldn't be any issue on Android 6. If he is seeing this issue consistently then it should be reported as a bug. Our sample app (DeviceDemo) that is tested as part of release certification uses camera and there was no issue reported on Samsung Android 6 devices. "

Comment: I guess I'll report it as a bug, I'll also test the DeviceDemo sample app on my emulated Android 6 platform and see if I get the same problem.

Comment: By the way, thanks for all that @Chris, really appreciate it. The bottom line is the app isn't working the same on Android 6 as it is on Android 5 and it's definitely crashing because of a permission issue. I should also note that the requested permission from that exception, isn't going into my generated Manifest.xml file for the build. So perhaps this is less about run-time requests and more about MAF generating the manifest file wrong? I've made a post on the Oracle forum about this but as of yet have no response, I might include this in the support ticket.

Comment: The DeviceDemo crashes with the same problem, and I can't find how to create a bug report on the Oracle site, any help appreciated @Chris

Comment: I've subsequently tested this on the Android Emulator with API 23 (Not API 23 N) and it works okay. I'm unable to test it on a device though. As such you'll need to submit an SR with Oracle Support.As a paid Oracle customer you should have access to this, have a chat to your team who purchased the licenses, they should have more details how you sign up to Oracle Support with your CSI and submit an SR.

Comment: @Chris, I use a Genymotion emulator running API 23 (Android 6.0.0) and it had the same results as running it on a physical Samsung S6 (unknown OS, just "latest version"). Why would they both be failing and yet its working for you? Not understanding this...Could it be a problem with Eclipse? Also, I'm not a paying Oracle customer, not sure where you got that from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE (22/08.2016):

This was actually happening because I was setting the target SDK to 23 in my build configurations. Downloading the new Eclipse simply reset this back to the default (21)

## Old Answer:

I solved this by downloading OEPE for Neon (I was using OEPE for Mars).

[Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html)

The application now correctly generates a popup requesting permission to use the camera.

Please note, this has created an issue with location services and the app crashes when requesting gps location, I have not yet discovered a fix or the source of the problem.